ffmpeg fetching PTS/DTS for data packets incorrectly
I have captured a transport stream through TSP command
Command: tsp -I ip port --source ip -O file stream_capture1.ts
then using ffprobe, below is the output which is capturing correct stream
Input #0, mpegts, from 'stream_capture1.ts':                                                         
  Duration: 20:56:00.19, start: 21971.910678, bitrate: 5 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : CS11G
      service_provider: ABC
    Stream #0:1[0x70]: Video: hevc (Rext) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 1920x540 [SAR 1:2 DAR 16:9], 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x71]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 379 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x72]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 143 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x73]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:5[0x75]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:6[0x76]: Data: bin_data (VANC / 0x434E4156)
  Program 2                                                                                          
    Metadata:                                                                                        
      service_name    : CS11H                                                                        
      service_provider: ABC                                                                         
    Stream #0:7[0x7a]: Video: hevc (Rext) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 1920x540 [SAR 1:2 DAR 16:9], 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:8[0x7b]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s
    Stream #0:9[0x7c]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 134 kb/s
    Stream #0:10[0x7d]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:11[0x7f]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:12[0x80]: Data: bin_data (VANC / 0x434E4156)

But when i am trying to capture the same transport stream using ffmpeg
Command: ffmpeg -i "udp://ip:port?localaddr=ip&sources=ip&overrun_nonfatal=1&buffer_size=4000000&fifo_size=1000000" -c copy -map 0 -vsync passthrough -copyts vanc_stream_ffmpeg.ts
and run ffprobe below is the output:
Input #0, mpegts, from 'vanc_stream_ffmpeg.ts':                                                      
  Duration: N/A, start: 44077.203733, bitrate: N/A  
  Program 1                                                                                          
    Metadata:                                                                                        
      service_name    : Service01       
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: hevc (Rext) (HEVC / 0x43564548), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 1920x540 [SAR 1:2 DAR 16:9], 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x102]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x103]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x104]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:5[0x105]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:6[0x106]: Video: hevc (Rext) (HEVC / 0x43564548), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 1920x540 [SAR 1:2 DAR 16:9], 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:7[0x107]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:8[0x108]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s
    Stream #0:9[0x109]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:10[0x10a]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:11[0x10b]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)

Now the problem with above output is, it is changing only data streams, it is not capturing the VANC data/data packets correctly and it is dropping the PTS/DTS values from the data packets only
**video, audio packets are correct
below is the output when i am checking packets using ffprobe
command: ffprobe -select_streams i:261 -show_packets -show_data vanc_stream_ffmpeg.ts
[PACKET]
codec_type=data
stream_index=5
pts=N/A
pts_time=N/A
dts=N/A
dts_time=N/A
duration=N/A
duration_time=N/A
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=124
pos=82714924
flags=K_
[SIDE_DATA]
side_data_type=MPEGTS Stream ID
[/SIDE_DATA]
data=
00000000: 0002 4001 6140 552a 5a9 544 f5d bf9a  ..@.a@U*ZiT...
00000010: a727 d2fc 651a b75 77d 2fa8 000 bea0  .'..e...s}/...
00000020: 0802 fa80 20b ea00 82f a02 00be a008  .... ..../....
00000030: 02fa 820 0bea 0080 2fa8 000 ba0 0802  ... ..../.....

[/PACKET] 

I have tried various flags to retrieve data packets coreectly without altering PTS/DTS
Flags i have used:

-c:d copy
-copyts
-fix_teletext_pts 1
-dts_delta_threshold threshold

Need solution so that ffmpeg command will fetch data packets from stream as same as Tsp command is fetching or needed any flag related to copy data packets without dropping PTS/DTS values.

If you want to capture the input as a raw bytestream, then you need to force the data format throughout, otherwise ffmpeg will try to interpret all streams and replace unrecognized ones with generic placeholder values.
ffmpeg -f data -i "udp://ip:port?localaddr=ip&sources=ip&overrun_nonfatal=1&buffer_size=4000000&fifo_size=1000000" -c copy -map 0 -f data vanc_stream_ffmpeg.ts

In logs below it is showing video, audio, subtitle data captured 0kb, this will be an issue i think, could you please help me with this also
Output #0, data, to 'vanc_stream_ffmpeg_1.ts':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
Stream #0:0: Data: none
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=  218500kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:218500kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%

when i am doing ffprobe on the captured stream data is capturing correct but it is also giving
[mpegts @ 0x562035d39f00] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mpegts @ 0x562035d39f00]  packet size mismatch
Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 0x555fca7abf00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 25 (Video: hevc ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

It means the capture didn't start from a keyframe. Add analyzeduration and probesize in front of the captured file.

ffmpeg -f data -i "udp://ip:port?localaddr=ip&sources=ip&overrun_nonfatal=1&buffer_size=4000000&fifo_size=1000000" -analyzeduration 50000000 -probesize 50000000 -c copy -map 0 -f data vanc_stream_ffmpeg_2.ts
Provided analyzeduration and probesize like this still i am getting video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:218500kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%

Hi, Actually my final goal is to fetch VANC data from incoming stream so when i am using -f data flag and running  ./klvanc_smpte2038 -i vanc_stream_ffmpeg.ts -P 0x76 on the fetched stream it is throwing segmentation fault(core dump) error, Can you please help me with this!

Add analyzeduration and probesize in front of the captured file. ffmpeg -analyzeduration 50000000 -probesize 50000000 -i vanc_stream_ffmpeg_2.ts ...

Hi @Gyan, thanks for your support so far, but still not getting results as you suggested i tried ffmpeg -analyzeduration 50000000 -probesize 50000000 -i vanc_stream_ffmpeg_2.ts -c copy -map 0 vanc_output_stream.ts saving output in vanc_output_stream.ts now the problem is same as before it is changing only data streams, it is not capturing the VANC data/data packets correctly and it is dropping the PTS/DTS values and with ./klvanc_smpte2038 script i am not getting any PES packets and Vanc packets from the stream.
h->PTS_DTS_flags is invalid
Error parsing packet
PES/VANC packets: 0

Also one thing with ffmpeg -f data -i "udp://10.0.0.2:5000?localaddr=10.0.0.2&sources=10.0.0.1&overrun_nonfatal=1&buffer_size=425984&fifo_size=1000000" -analyzeduration 50000000 -probesize 50000000 -c copy -map 0 -f data vanc_stream_ffmpeg_2.ts command when i am doing ffprobe on vanc_stream_ffmpeg_2.ts captured file i found some warning/errors like [mpegts @ 0x55f1af0a7f00] PES packet size mismatch Last message repeated 19 times maybe this is the issue can you please help me with this!!

ffmpeg can't process VANC data so you can only capture it using the data format, you can't process it further.

Hi @Gyan For processing we are using klvanc_smpte2038 CLI tool which takes input as transport stream and fetch PES Packets in VANC space but using .ts file which is captured from ffmpeg, after processing some packets in it, is throwing segmentation fault error whereas .ts file captured from tsp is able to provide all packets using the same klvanc_smpte2038 CLI tool.
So, is there any other input data flag or anything for ffmpeg which can be used to avoid memory coruption or to capture data in correct format as tsp command is capturing, is there any documentation for this data format flag

klvanc output for the ts file captured with ffmpeg
->payload  = 00 00  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
klvanc output for the ts file captured with tsp
->payload  = 00 00  Total PES packets found: 1449 Total VANC packets found: 2898 Total VANC checksum failures: 0
